# Animating one component in an array of components in Angular4

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and I trying to animate a flip on a single component(card) in an array of components in Angular.

I have 10 cards in the array, and I want just the clicked card to flip around. So far I have the code so that when any of the cards are clicked, they all flip around. However I would like just the clicked card to flip.

Here is the card component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  animations: [
    trigger('flipState', [
      state('active', style({
        transform: 'rotateY(179.9deg)'
      })),
      state('inactive', style({
        transform: 'rotateY(0)'
      })),
      transition('active => inactive', animate('500ms ease-out')),
      transition('inactive => active', animate('500ms ease-in'))
    ])  
  ]
})
export class CardComponent {
  @Input() data: Person[];

  flip: string = 'inactive';

  toggleFlip() {
    this.flip = (this.flip == 'inactive') ? 'active' : 'inactive';
  }
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
 <div *ngFor="let p of data" (click)="toggleFlip()" [@flipState]="flip">
    <div class="card__inner">
      {{ p.name }}
      <h3>{{ p.age }}</h3>
      {{ p.jobTitle }}
    </div>
  </div>
```

I was thinking I would need to identify the clicked card and find a way to change the flip "state" on only that card, but I'm not sure how to go about this, or if its even the best approach.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the animation trigger needed to be added into every list item.